# геолокация для бота

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше считывать координаты геолокации пользователя в боте для телеграм
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых нужно определить тип объекта `Messsage`, получаемого вашим ботом. Если тип `Location`, то работаете с его полями `longitude` и `latitude` - это и есть координаты, переданные пользователем.
Можете ознакомиться с [документацией](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api):
Объект [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message)
Тип [Location](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#location)

Comment: Спасибо! Подскажите еще, как правильно определить тип?

Comment: Правильно так, как описано в документации или реализовано в библиотеке, которая используется для написания бота. Вы на чём пишете-то?